# Effect of step pulse shape on stepper motor function

Tags: stepper-motor

I am using Nema17 12 v motors with A4988 drivers for a project that drives an XY stage. I am programming the pulses to the STEP pin of the drivers in C and I can control the frequency and the shape of each pulse. I was wondering if anyone can tell me (or point me to a reference about) what is the relationship between pulse SHAPE and performance of the motor (as distinct from pulse FREQUENCY). By 'performance' I mean any effect on torque or the reliability of converting the step signal into a rotor step. For example, what would be the difference (for the same frequency) of applying these pulse shapes to the STEP pin of the driver:

`a) -_____-_____-_____-_____ etc. (most of the cycle the signal is 'off'/'logical zero')
b) ---___---___---___---___ etc. (equal time for 'on' and 'off')
c) -----_-----_-----_-----_ etc. (for most of each cycle the signal is 'on'/'1')`

I am currently using form (b) for my pulses (as most examples I have seen do this) but I was wondering what advantage/disadvantage there may be for changing this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this driver, I think your changes will have no effect whatsoever.

A rising edge on the STEP line simply tells the driver to advance the motor firing sequence. It will advance and then hold and wait for the next step. How long you hold the signal high will not change anything.

Here's a a chart from the datasheet. Notice that there are no vertical lines at the STEP falling edges. You can also see that when the edge occurs, nothing changes in the output waveform.

[image: output current vs step signal chart]

There *are* settings you can change that will change the pulse shape that the motor sees. For example micro-stepping and decay settings, but these are set elsewhere.